# ¿Error al crear un store procedure con rango de fechas?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

tengo una consulta:

Me genera error al crear mi store procedure cuando le paso un rango de fechas.Sin embargo si solo le paso el id de proyecto funciona bien, el problema es cuando al where le paso un rango de fechas

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PA_Control_horas_Proyecto]
@IdProyecto varchar(6),@Fecha1 date, @Fecha2 date

/*
    EXEC [PA_Control_horas_Proyecto] '103569','15-09-2019','15-10-2019'
*/
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
as
begin
IF @Fecha1 is null 
   or @Fecha2 is null 
   or @Fecha1 > @Fecha2
  return -1;
DECLARE @SQLDynamic NVARCHAR(MAX)-- STRING QUE CONTENDRA TODO
--DECLARE @FinalDate NVARCHAR(50)=right(@MesAño,4)+'-'+'01-'+left(@MesAño,2)-- creamos el año + el mes + el primer dia

--obtiene el primer dia del mes
;with CTE_DAY_Recursive as (
SELECT @Fecha1 as DayDINAMIC 
union all
SELECT dateadd (day, +1, DayDINAMIC)   
  from CTE_DAY_Recursive
  where DayDINAMIC < @Fecha2
)
SELECT  @SQLDynamic=COALESCE(@SQLDynamic+',','')+'['+CAST(DayDINAMIC    AS nvarchar(20))+']' 
FROM CTE_DAY_Recursive  --Obtenemos los registros 

DECLARE @SQLFULL NVARCHAR(MAX)='

select * from
(
select 
    Id_Colaborador as ''DNI'',
    Nombre_Colaborador as ''COLABORADOR'',
    dbo.FU_Desc_Proyecto(Id_Unidad_Organizativa) as ''PROYECTO UO'',
    Nro_Proyecto_Registro +'' ''+Descripcion_Proyecto_Registro as ''PROYECTO ASIGNADO'',
    Fecha_Registro,
    sum(Hora_Registro) as ''Hora_Registro''
    from Sigeri
    where Nro_Proyecto_Registro = '+@IdProyecto+' and Fecha_Registro>='+@Fecha1+' and Fecha_Registro<='+@Fecha2+'
    group by Id_Colaborador,Nombre_Colaborador,Id_Unidad_Organizativa,Nro_Proyecto_Registro,Fecha_Registro,Descripcion_Proyecto_Registro
)s
pivot(
    max(Hora_Registro)
    for[Fecha_Registro] in --(select Fecha_Registro FROM Sigeri)
('+@SQLDynamic+') --Le pasamos los registros
)p'


EXEC(@SQLFULL)
end
```

He probado sin el rango de fechas y funciona a la perfección.Además de ello uso pivot para convertir las fechas en columnas.

El mensaje de error que me muestra es el siguiente

```
Los tipos de datos varchar y date son incompatibles con el operador add.
```

Comment: Podriamos mostrar un ejemplo de como estas tratando de llamarlo?

Comment: EXEC [PA_Control_horas_Proyecto] '103569','15-09-2019','15-10-2019'

Comment: no se puede crear el store procedure al agregarle esta parte de rango de fechas  and Fecha_Registro>='+@Fecha1+' and Fecha_Registro<='+@Fecha2+'

Comment: Ah ya se cual es tu error

Comment: tener en cuenta que el campo Fecha_Registro es date, y los parámetros que les paso son date también, y quizás del problema estuve viendo en otro foro que cuando es @SQLFULL  NVARCHAR(MAX) no admite date desde esta  url https://rstopup.com/los-tipos-de-datos-varcharmax-y-la-fecha-son-incompatibles-en-el-complemento-operador.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hola te anexo un ejemplo para que veas el detalle esta en tus fechas no puedes ponerlo solo asi hay que realizar un cast

Aqui debes de hacer el cambio te anexo un ejemplo.

```
where Nro_Proyecto_Registro = '''+@IdProyecto+''' and Fecha_Registro>='''+CAST(@Fecha1 AS nvarchar(50))+''' and Fecha_Registro<='''+CAST(@Fecha2 AS NVARCHAR(50))+'''
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6dd4a8b50b0fca0b9a6983244149e8e0

Cambiarias el Print por el EXEC para poder ejecutarlo.

Saludos

Comment: Conoces a [Bobby Tables](https://es.xkcd.com/strips/exploits-de-una-madre/)?

Answer (score 1):

Este es un código que de ser tomado como ejemplo, abre las puertas a la inyección de SQL. Nunca se deben de concatenar los valores de los parámetros. Siempre debemos parametrizar las consultas. Para esto, tenemos `sp_executesql` que permite definir y enviar parámetros a nuestras consultas.

Dejo un ejemplo con unas cuantas mejoras en cuanto a mejores prácticas y formato.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PA_Control_horas_Proyecto]
    @IdProyecto varchar(6)  ,
    @Fecha1 date            ,
    @Fecha2 date            ,
/*
    EXEC [PA_Control_horas_Proyecto] '103569','15-09-2019','15-10-2019'
*/
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AS

IF @Fecha1 is null 
   or @Fecha2 is null 
   or @Fecha1 > @Fecha2
  RETURN -1;

DECLARE @SQLDynamic NVARCHAR(MAX);-- STRING QUE CONTENDRA TODO

WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(DD, @Fecha1, @Fecha2) + 1)
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT  @SQLDynamic = COALESCE( @SQLDynamic + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(CONVERT( char(10), DATEADD( dd, n, @Fecha1), 120)) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9)
FROM cteTally;

DECLARE @SQLFULL NVARCHAR(MAX)='

SELECT * 
FROM(
        SELECT 
            Id_Colaborador as ''DNI'',
            Nombre_Colaborador as ''COLABORADOR'',
            dbo.FU_Desc_Proyecto(Id_Unidad_Organizativa) as ''PROYECTO UO'',
            Nro_Proyecto_Registro +'' ''+Descripcion_Proyecto_Registro as ''PROYECTO ASIGNADO'',
            Fecha_Registro,
            SUM(Hora_Registro) as ''Hora_Registro''
        FROM Sigeri
        WHERE Nro_Proyecto_Registro = @IdProyecto 
        AND   Fecha_Registro >= @Fecha1 
        AND   Fecha_Registro <= @Fecha2
        GROUP BY Id_Colaborador,Nombre_Colaborador,Id_Unidad_Organizativa,Nro_Proyecto_Registro,Fecha_Registro,Descripcion_Proyecto_Registro
    )s
PIVOT(
    MAX(Hora_Registro)
    FOR [Fecha_Registro] IN --(select Fecha_Registro FROM Sigeri)
('+@SQLDynamic+') --Le pasamos los registros
)p;';

--PRINT @SQLFULL
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLFULL, N'@IdProyecto varchar(6),@Fecha1 date, @Fecha2 date', @IdProyecto, @Fecha1, @Fecha2;

GO
```