# ¿Cómo poner 2 pivot en sql server?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Hola a todos tengo una consulta:

Tengo un store procedure en sql server que contiene una consulta que muestra las horas de los trabajadores por cada fecha usando pivot para la fila fecha y la convierta a columna.

Lo que quiero es poner otro pivot más con nombre de columna TIPO REGISTRO que se llenará de una funcion que devuelve `REGISTRO`, `NO REGISTRO` que esta en la consulta del store procedure

Aquí dejo el código del store procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PA_Control_horas_Proyecto]
@IdProyecto varchar(6),@Fecha1 date, @Fecha2 date

/*
    EXEC [PA_Control_horas_Proyecto] '103569','15-09-2019','15-10-2019'
*/
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
as
begin
IF @Fecha1 is null 
   or @Fecha2 is null 
   or @Fecha1 > @Fecha2
  return -1;
DECLARE @SQLDynamic NVARCHAR(MAX)-- STRING QUE CONTENDRA TODO

--obtiene el primer dia del mes
;with CTE_DAY_Recursive as (
SELECT @Fecha1 as DayDINAMIC 
union all
SELECT dateadd (day, +1, DayDINAMIC)   
  from CTE_DAY_Recursive
  where DayDINAMIC < @Fecha2
)
SELECT  @SQLDynamic=COALESCE(@SQLDynamic+',','')+'['+CAST(DayDINAMIC    AS nvarchar(20))+']' 
FROM CTE_DAY_Recursive  --Obtenemos los registros 

DECLARE @SQLFULL NVARCHAR(MAX)='

select * from
(
select 
    Id_Colaborador as ''DNI'',
    Nombre_Colaborador as ''COLABORADOR'',
    dbo.FU_Desc_Proyecto(Id_Unidad_Organizativa) as ''PROYECTO UO'',
    Nro_Proyecto_Registro +'' ''+Descripcion_Proyecto_Registro as ''PROYECTO ASIGNADO'',
    Fecha_Registro,
    sum(Hora_Registro) as ''Hora_Registro'',
    dbo.fu_horas_dia(Id_Colaborador,Fecha_Registro) as ''TIPO REGISTRO''
    from Sigeri
    where Nro_Proyecto_Registro = '''+@IdProyecto+''' and Fecha_Registro>='''+convert(varchar(20),@Fecha1,105)+''' and Fecha_Registro<='''+convert(varchar(20),@Fecha2,105)+'''
    group by Id_Colaborador,Nombre_Colaborador,Id_Unidad_Organizativa,Nro_Proyecto_Registro,Fecha_Registro,Descripcion_Proyecto_Registro
)s
pivot(
    max(Hora_Registro)
    for[Fecha_Registro] in --(select Fecha_Registro FROM Sigeri)
('+@SQLDynamic+') --Le pasamos los registros
)p'


exec(@SQLFULL)
end
```

Aquí dejo la imagen de lo que genera el store procedure, las fechas están ahora en columna por que estoy usando pivot

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que deseo ahora es pasarle otro pivot más para que quede así

Ejemplo

```
2019-10-10|TIPO REGISTRO|2019-10-11|TIPO REGISTRO
   9        REGISTRO       0         NO REGISTRO
   0       NO REGISTRO     9         REGISTRO


--Segundo Pivot: quiero que me muestre en el nombre de la columna TIPO REGISTRO y sus valores que sea lo que devuelve la
  funcion de la consulta que esta mas arriba
pivot(
    max(dbo.FU_hora_dias)
    for[TIPO REGISTRO] in 
('+@SQLDynamic+') --Le pasamos [TIPO REGISTRO],[TIPO REGISTRO] la cantidad de fechas que genere también generará de este tipo de titulo
)q'
```

Comment: Esto se pudo haber solucionado desde [tu pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/306390/error-al-crear-un-store-procedure-con-rango-de-fechas/306406). Por favor, pon datos de prueba y resultados esperados completos. Tu descripción indica que no quieres hacer un segundo pivote sino que quieres repetir una columna en cada fecha.

Comment: Lo que pido es usar dos pivot , la imagen mostrada con anterioridad es como esta hasta el momento mi store procedure, El ejemplo es el resultado esperado

Comment: El ejemplo que pones después de la imagen, no es un pivote.

Comment: Eso es lo que deseo tener, pero no sé si realmente se puede hacer con pivot

Comment: Cómo ya tengo un código establecido, es por ello que pedía si se podía realizar con pivot. ya que además de usar pivot, genero las columnas dinámicamente. Y cambiar todo me costaría un poco más ya que no tengo muchos conocimientos en sql

Comment: El problema no es el código que tienes establecido (que no es el más eficiente), el problema es que no has podido dar un [mcve] para poder tener un punto de inicio y un objetivo para obtener una solución óptima.